# WordPress Virus

Tags: wordpress, redirect, code-injection

I have a problem with WordPress site. First thing is I cant open /wp-admin beacuse: too many redirections. Second I cant event open my site because it redirect me to other site myspaceid.space which redirect to random page. I've been searching anwer in google, I've been looking for injection in themes file, in main core wordpress file and I couldn't find a problem.
Any sugestions ?

http://jkconcept.net

Comment: Have you checked .htaccess file? It could be possible source of the problem.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [FAQ My website was hacked | WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

Comment: .htaccess is fine

Comment: I can see the page is almost full loaded and then it redirect to myspaceid.space

Comment: Disable all plugins and see if the problem persists, if it doesn't, reinstall one by one until the problem starts again. If the issue is still there with all plugins disabled, then the problem is most likely with your theme. You may want to consider installing [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) as well, which can scan your site and detect issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open your phpmyadmin, go to wp_options and check if your URL is correctly fowarding to wordpress.

Comment: `wp_config.php` doesn't use a URL, and if the URL was set incorrectly in the `wp_options` table it wouldn't load the site at all.

Comment: @APAD1 i meant to say wp_options, not config, just edited my post. But i guess its not the problem.